# AWS Cognito workaround for aws:username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am writing a user policy using AWS Cognito User Pools for an app that needs to be compatible with an old ad hoc user management system we had previously used on S3 with IAM while we move to a better user management model using Cognito.

The old system used `arn:aws:s3:::[Our Bucket Name]/${aws:username}/*` in the group policy to only allow a user access to objects using their username. I had thought that using the same username in Cognito would allow us to use a duplicate role policy allowing the Cognito users the same access, but according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html), the `aws:username` is not present for Cognito; that only has the `aws:userid`, which, if I am reading this right, is essentially a randomly generated unique string that has nothing to do with the username and so cannot be used for this purpose.

Is there any other way I can give the Cognito user access to a given IAM username's folder in S3 on the basis of the same name through a role policy? The only way I can think of is to make custom policies on a per-user basis, but I would prefer to keep changes to our existing user creation system to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** don't mix IAM with Cognito. Write an app/service/api to provide the objects to the authorized user.

**Long Answer**: IAM is for admins or services of AWS. Do not mix it with the Cognito. Cognito is for storing and providing tokens to your users. You might ask how to provide the objects within `bucket-name/user-test` to `user-test`:

1. **Store User Access Rights in S3**: For each user have a bucket `access-rights/user-test`. It should conclude the user rights; for example you can have as a Json:

   {
     username: string, 
     access-bucket-name: string 
   }
2. **Additional Service**: You can have authentication service to check the user is authenticated (using Cognito), then based on the body of the token, get the username; and check its rights (first step) and the application should provide the object from the initial bucket the user wants to access.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not clear on how a JSON can grant access rights. I don't think making an outside authentication service is going to be an option.

Comment: @Trevortni the new service job, that I mentioned, act as a gateway of cognito and objects within s3 buckets. The additional bucket which has the access rights are the checkpoints for the service to give grants to the user. You could in fact drop the policy related Json and just check for authenticity of the user and then get the object based on the username alone; however in the future if a new service and or data added to your stack, then you need to redo this as well as coming up with a place to hold the policies. Hope I made sense :-)